# Include Jade template with Config Variables

Tags: node.js, pug

So my plan is to have a common `config.jade` file that contains variables that are used in a number of templates. Such as API keys and their ilk.

My setup so far.

`config.jade`

```
- var GREETING = "HOWDY!"
```

`template.jade`

```
include ./config
h1 #{GREETING}
```

All I get is a blank `<h1>`. What gives? Shouldn't this work?

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me using jade 1.9.2.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an extra `s` in `template.jade`.

```
include ./config
```

Comment: @Breedly, note that Jade does not support dynamic include, so all `include` statements are parsed during compile-time. What this means that, if you are using a web server that caches Jade templates, you have to restart the server to account for changes in config.jade. HTH.